# PHP Laravel Convert array value to upper case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have an array with multiples values in my Laravel project:

```
array:1434 [▼
  0 => array:53 [▼
    "contact" => "ANA (dependienta)"
    "mail" => "example@mail.com"
    "phone2" => ""
    "phone3" => ""
    "web" => "0"
    "active" => true
    "province" => "Zaragoza"

  ]
  1 => array:53 [▼
    "contact" => "JACKELINE * VIVIANA"
    "mail" => "mail@example.com"
    "phone2" => ""
    "phone3" => ""
    "web" => "0"
    "active" => true
    "province" => "Barcelona"

  ]
```

I want transform to upper case only the province value, I want to get this result:

```
array:1434 [▼
  0 => array:53 [▼
    "contact" => "ANA (dependienta)"
    "mail" => "example@mail.com"
    "phone2" => ""
    "phone3" => ""
    "web" => "0"
    "active" => true
    "province" => "ZARAGOZA"

  ]
  1 => array:53 [▼
    "contact" => "JACKELINE * VIVIANA"
    "mail" => "mail@example.com"
    "phone2" => ""
    "phone3" => ""
    "web" => "0"
    "active" => true
    "province" => "BARCELONA"

  ]
```

Exists any method or way to make this with Laravel Collection or other alternatives?

Comment: post your php code please

Comment: don´t have php code, only have the result of my array

Comment: Down-voting for the lack of PHP code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're getting data from DB by using Eloquent, you could [create an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
public function getProvince($value)
{
    return strtoupper($value);
}
```

If not, you could change it manually:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $data[$i]['province'] = strtoupper($data[$i]['province']);
}
```

Comment: I don´t use eloquent, I´m using a API to get the data

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to make just first letter in upper case and the rest in lower case. Fixed the code.

Answer (score 3):

`$collection` is the array of objects, then try to use this way :

```
$collection = collect($array);

$keyed = $collection->keyBy(function ($item) {
    return strtoupper($item['province']);
});

$keyed->all();
```

Comment: @Antonio Morales I wonder why did you tick this answer? I've just tested this code and it doesn't give result you want. `keyBy()` will change indexes from `0`, `1` etc to uppercased province string and will leave `province` as is.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Str::upper`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-upper) method converts the given string to uppercase:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$string = Str::upper('laravel');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($rp_shops); $i++) { 
    $rp_shops[$i]['province'] = strtoupper($rp_shops[$i]['province']); 
} 
dd($rp_shops)
```

or

```
foreach ($rp_shops as $key => $rp_shop) { 
    $rp_shops[$key]['province'] = strtoupper($rp_shop['province']); 
} 
dd($rp_shops)
```